# error when trying to add quantity in windows form

Tags: c#

when i try to enter quantity and update the tblcart error shows that as shown in the picture the error comes as incorrect syntax near sdate..can you guys help me solve this problem..i have listed both quantity form and my posform codes below and you can also see the error in the pictures.

[image]
[image]

This is quantity form code

```
    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace POSsystem
    {
    public partial class frmQty : Form
    {
    //code to connect sql database 
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
    DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    private String pcode;
    private double price;
    private string transno;
    string stitle = "Simple POS System";
    frmPOS fpos;
    public frmQty(frmPOS frmpos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
        fpos = frmpos;
    }

    private void frmQty_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void ProductDetails(String pcode, double price, String transno)
    {
        this.pcode = pcode;
        this.price = price;
        this.transno = transno;
    }

    private void frmQty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void txtQty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar==13) && (txtQty.Text != String.Empty))
        {
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("insert into tblcart (transno, pcode, price, qty, sdate) values                 
    (@transno, @pcode, @price, @qty, @sdate", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transno", transno);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", pcode);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", int.Parse(txtQty.Text));
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", DateTime.Now);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            fpos.txtSearch.Clear();
            fpos.txtSearch.Focus();
            this.Dispose();

        }
    }
    }
    }
```

`
this is the code of posform

```
    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace POSsystem
    {
    public partial class frmPOS : Form
    {
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
    string stitle = "Simple POS System";


    public frmPOS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GetTransno()
    {
        try
        {
            string sdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string transno;
            int count;
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("select top 1 transno from tblcart where transno like '" + sdate +         
     "%' order by id desc", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows) {
                transno = dr[0].ToString();
                count = int.Parse(transno.Substring(8, 4));
                lblTransno.Text = sdate + (count + 1);
            } else {
                transno = sdate + "1001";
                lblTransno.Text = transno;
            } dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, stitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
       }
     
          private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        GetTransno();
        txtSearch.Enabled = true;
        txtSearch.Focus();
    }

    private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtSearch.Text == String.Empty) { return; }
            else
            {
                cn.Open();
                cm = new SqlCommand("select * from tblproduct where barcode like '" + txtSearch.Text 
    + "'", cn);
                dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    frmQty frm = new frmQty(this);
                    frm.ProductDetails(dr["pcode"].ToString(), double.Parse(dr["price"].ToString()), 
      lblTransno.Text);
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                }
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, stitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
      }
     }
     }

     `
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on your INSERT sql.

Comment: can you tell me the line...like can copy and past the line here from the code above with correction

Comment: Search on @sDate, it'll jump out at you.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score -1):

very likely is this line `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", DateTime.Now);`

try using

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", $"'{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}'");
```

not sure about your data schema, but pass a string instead of a DateTime to it.
the above sample code omits the time portion, so make the adjustment you want

Comment: ok thank you soo much ill try this and let you know...you are awesome